# JWT not send when refresh page with F5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm try to authorizing users with JWT. I have study here: [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction/)

I have a problem when the user refresh the page. When user make an ajax request there is no problem because I have added `beforeSend` in the ajax request like so:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '...',
            type: 'post',
            data: jsonObject,
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                var completeToken = localStorage.getItem('JWT');

                if(completeToken != null ){
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", completeToken);
                }
            }});
```

When user made a no ajax-request, the JWT token is not send to server. There is any solution for this? I think to use cookies + JWT but I keep this for last chance.

Comment: you need to append the header to the page as well using the server side language or adding the header in the server settings

Comment: I use Spring for back-end. If client does not send a token, how can I know the token of the current user that my server should add in the header?

Comment: the token is saved in localstorage, you should use it from there

Comment: I know that, but how F5 button can send the token store in localStorage?